# python - backward slash is removed while referring to path in network on windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd

```
netowrk_path = '\\shared_storage\test.txt'
cmd = f'/c copy {netowrk_path} D:\\temp'
print(cmd)
```

this prints and gives error while copying

```
/c copy \shared_storage test.txt D:\temp
```

but it should actually print

```
/c copy \\shared_storage test.txt D:\temp
```

Comment: Backslashes are interpreted specially in Python string literals, prefix the string with "r" like e. g. `r'\\shared_storage'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

backslash(\) is a way to escape certain characters [learn more](https://www.pitt.edu/%7Enaraehan/python2/tutorial7.html)

you can define the strings as raw strings

```
string = r'\\somenetworkpath'
print(string)
```

output:
`\\somenetworkpath`

[read more about the raw string](https://www.journaldev.com/23598/python-raw-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`repr`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/repr) in the following way:

```
print(repr(cmd))
```

This will give you the desired output

You can use [raw string](https://www.journaldev.com/23598/python-raw-string#:%7E:text=Python%20raw%20string%20is%20created,treated%20as%20an%20escape%20character.) and format in the following way:

```
netowrk_path = r'\\shared_storage\test.txt'
cmd = rf'/c copy {netowrk_path} D:\\temp'
print(cmd)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all single `\` with double slash `\\` or make it a raw string using r as suggested above.